# mongodb: replace an element in an array with one or more elements

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

given a collection such as :

```
{
   _id: 1,
   fruits: [ "apples", "pears", "oranges", "grapes", "bananas" ],
}
{
   _id: 2,
   fruits: [ "plums", "kiwis", "oranges"],
}
{
   _id: 3,
   fruits: [ "plums", "kiwis", "oranges", "bananas", "apples" ],
}
```

I want to replace all instances of "bananas" in with "cherries" and "dates". So the resulting collection will be:

```
{
   _id: 1,
   fruits: [ "apples", "pears", "oranges", "grapes", "cherries", "dates"],
}
{
   _id: 2,
   fruits: [ "plums", "kiwis", "oranges"],
}
{
   _id: 3,
   fruits: [ "plums", "kiwis", "oranges", "cherries", "dates", "apples"],
}
```

One method I have used through pymongo:

```html
for document in db.collection.find({'fruits':'bananas'}):
  fruits_list = document['fruits']
  new_fruits_list = []
  for fruit in fruit_list:
    if fruit != 'bananas':
      new_fruit_list.append(fruit)
    else:
      for new_fruit in ['cherries','dates']:
        new_fruit_list.append(new_fruit)

  db.collection.update({'_id' : document['_id']}, {'$set' : {'fruits' : new_fruit_list}})
```

I am looking for a more efficient method using [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/modify-documents/) command to $pull/remove the matched element and $push with $each modifier to insert the new elements. But I am stumped at finding the $position of array at which the push operations are to be performed. Another caveat is that I want to preserve the positions of the old fruit for the new fruits. i.e. first new fruit will have same position as the old fruit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB update for `push and pull` for same key in same command not working for more [check this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1050).

So First you should `pull` all  `bananas` from `fruits` array using this command

```
db.collection.update({},{"$pull":{"fruits":"bananas"}},true,false)
```

First `true` for multiple documents like `{multi:true}` so it pull and `bananas` from `fruits` array, and then add replacement of bananas as "cherries" and "dates" using `$push` like this :

```
db.collection.update({},{"$push":{"fruits":{"$each":["cherries","dates"]}}},true,true)
```

**EDIT**

If you want ton insert only those documents contains `bananas` then first push and then pull like this :

```
db.collection.update({"fruits":{"$in":["bananas"]}},{"$push":{"fruits":{"$each":["cherries","dates"]}}},true,true)
```

and then pull `bananas` :

```
db.collection.update({"fruits":{"$in":["bananas"]}},{"$pull":{"fruits":"bananas"}},true,true)
```

**Second Edit**

If `cherries and dates` inserted with position `bananas` then first find out position of `bananas` in array but this not possible direct with mongo query so here used some scripting code ( here I used JavaScript ) using [mongo bulk](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/Bulk.find.updateOne/#Bulk.find.updateOne) it will update documents check below code :

```
var bulk = db.collectionName.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var counter = 0;
db.collectionName.find({"fruits":{"$in":["bananas"]}}).forEach(function(data){
var postion = data.fruits.indexOf("bananas");
    bulk.find({"_id":data._id}).updateOne({"$push":{"fruits":{"$each":["cherries","dates"],"$position":postion}}},true,true);
    bulk.find({"_id":data._id}).updateOne({"$pull":{"fruits":"bananas"}},true,true);
     counter++;
if ( counter % 1000 == 0 ) {
          bulk.execute();
          bulk = db.collectionName.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
      }
});

if ( counter % 1000 != 0 ){
    bulk.execute();
}
```

[$postion](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/update/position/) modifier specifies the location in the array at which the `$push` operator insert elements. Without the `$position` modifier, the `$push` operator inserts elements to the end of the array.

Comment: The $push command will append "cherries" and "dates" to all documents in the collection. This can be avoided by doing the $push first using "bananas" in query and then doing the $pull. But this would still not preserve the positions.

Comment: As per my understanding you want to push `cherries and dates` in `bananas` position and pull `bananas` right?

Comment: check new edited answer I am not aware `pymongo` so I posted Java script .

Comment: Only the `$position` modifier needs to be supplied. But I don't know how to find position of `bananas` .

Comment: mongoDB still not provide any operator to find out position of array element check this [jira issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-828)  or [this also](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/pXDmJSIbqgc) so you need to find out position of elements  using scripting in my `second edit` I used java script to find out position using `indexOf("bananas")` method